# Transform data by truncating/removing similar information from rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have source data in SQL Server table as per below
[image: Source]

and needed to be transformed as per below
[image: Transformation]

Please do let me know how this can be achieved.

Here is the code to create table and insert sample data.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.tbl_TestData 
(Level1 NVARCHAR(25),Level2 NVARCHAR(25),Level3 NVARCHAR(25),Level4 
NVARCHAR(25),Level5 NVARCHAR(25),
Level6 NVARCHAR(25),Level7 NVARCHAR(25),Level8 NVARCHAR(25),Level9 
NVARCHAR(25)
)

INSERT INTO dbo.tbl_TestData 
(Level1,Level2,Level3,Level4,Level5,Level6,Level7,Level8,Level9)
VALUES ('Shared Services','Shared Services','Shared Services','Shared 
Services','Shared Services','Shared Service Functions','Finance','AFO 
Total','AFO BAU'),
('Shared Services','Shared Services','Shared Services','Shared 
Services','Shared Services','Shared Service Functions','IT','TOTAL 
IT','GLOBAL INFRASTRUCTURE'),
('UKI Total','UKI Total','Insurance Total','Manufacturing / 
Segments','Claims','Commercial SME','Regional Trading','Commercial 
SME','North Operations'),
('ACS OBSOLETE','ACS OBSOLETE','ACS OBSOLETE','ACS OBSOLETE','ACS 
OBSOLETE','ACS OBSOLETE','ACS OBSOLETE','ACS OBSOLETE','SP Central')
```

Comment: Please don't post images of data, it isn't helpful to the volunteers you're asking help from. Post data as formatted `text`, or as DDL and DML Statement. What is your question here, as "let me know how" isn't very specific: Using a SQL Statement would be a perfectly valid answer to that question. Instead shows us your attempts, explain your goal, and tell us why your attempts didn't work. Stack Overflow isn't a free coding service, so please don't treat it as one. Thanks.

Comment: Something seems off with the structure of this table if you are trying to group data across columns.

Comment: Hey @Larnu, Thank you, ill add create and insert scripts

Comment: @Babulal how was this data generated in the first place? It's probably a *lot* easier to modify that statement instead of trying to modify the results. For example, the first screenshot looks like the results of a GROUP BY. A `WITH ROLLUP` would produce subtotal rows whose columns would look just like the second screenshot

Comment: @Babulal working with the *Result* on the other hand, would require an UNPIVOT to get the values are rows, and then another GROUP BY WITH ROLLUP to create what you could get from the original query

Comment: Hey @PanagiotisKanavos, this data is received in the format mentioned, Could you help me with WITH ROLLUP function

Comment: Can you post your attempt(s) too please, along with the other details I asked for please?

Comment: Hey @Larnu, already added SQL Statements and i am working on the result. Can i have your inputs to this problem?

Comment: I'll be happy to help, but you still need to address my original comment before I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me start by saying just because you **can** doesn't mean you **should**. This data is not structured structured properly as several of the comments state.

The first step is to [un-pivot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017) the data. Using the below query you can see this reorganizes the data. Please note, if the order of the rows matters then the `over` clause of the `row_number()` function will need to be modified.

```
select
      upvt.RowNum
    , upvt.LevelNum
    , upvt.LevelValue
from
    (
        select
              row_number() over (order by [level1]) as RowNum
            , a.Level1, a.Level2, a.Level3
            , a.Level4, a.Level5, a.Level6
            , a.Level7, a.Level8, a.Level9
        from
            dbo.tbl_TestData as a
    ) as a
unpivot
    (
        LevelValue for LevelNum in (
              [Level1], [Level2], [Level3]
            , [Level4], [Level5], [Level6]
            , [Level7], [Level8], [Level9])
    ) as upvt
```

Using the un-pivoted data you can group by the values and find the minimum level for each value. This can then be re-ordered and pivoted back to **almost** produce the desired result. Note, the row order is not the same if that matters.

```
select
    pvt.Level1
  , pvt.Level2
  , pvt.Level3
  , pvt.Level4
  , pvt.Level5
  , pvt.Level6
  , pvt.Level7
  , pvt.Level8
  , pvt.Level9
from
    (
        select
              a.RowNum
            , a.LevelValue
            , 'Level' + cast(row_number() over (partition by a.RowNum order by min(a.LevelNum)) as char(1)) as NewLevelNum
        from
            (
                select
                      upvt.RowNum
                    , upvt.LevelNum
                    , upvt.LevelValue
                from
                    (
                        select
                              row_number() over (order by [level1]) as RowNum
                            , a.Level1, a.Level2, a.Level3
                            , a.Level4, a.Level5, a.Level6
                            , a.Level7, a.Level8, a.Level9
                        from
                            dbo.tbl_TestData as a
                    ) as a
                unpivot
                    (
                        LevelValue for LevelNum in (
                              [Level1], [Level2], [Level3]
                            , [Level4], [Level5], [Level6]
                            , [Level7], [Level8], [Level9])
                    ) as upvt
            ) as a
        group by
            a.RowNum, a.LevelValue
    ) as a
pivot
    (
    max(LevelValue)
    for NewLevelNum in (
          [Level1], [Level2], [Level3]
        , [Level4], [Level5], [Level6]
        , [Level7], [Level8], [Level9])
    ) as pvt
```